# Best way of implementing a scrolling navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, navigation-drawer

I have been adding a navigation drawer to one of my apps, and I started to wonder whether or not it would be better to switch from using a `ListView` to multiple `TextView`s for the navigation drawer list items. Looking at the [Google Design Guidelines on Navigation Drawer content (specifically the section on 'Scrolling')](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content), I noticed that it may look nicer with multiple `TextView`s.

At the moment, I am using a `ListView` and `ImageView` in my navigation drawer (it looks a little like [this](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7LWFrRENhVVJrYzQ/patterns_navdrawer_selection1.png). However, when I scroll in my navigation drawer (I do this by turning my device landscape as there are not enough items in my list yet), only the `ListView` scrolls, and the `ImageView` stays as it is. I want it to be able to scoll more like [this, where the `ImageView` is also scrolled with the `ListView`](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7MFMyT2ZxcTZXb3c/patterns_navdrawer_scrolling2.png).

Additionally, I found that my `ListView` in my navigation drawer does not have the ripple effects [as shown in this image](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7LWFrRENhVVJrYzQ/patterns_navdrawer_selection1.png) although other `ListView`s in my other `Activity`s and `Fragment`s do.

What are the issues I am facing and how could I go about resolving these?

### Update:

In Google's I/O App (2014), there seems to be a `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the [navigation drawer layout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/navdrawer.xml) which I think is responsible for the list of items shown. Could someone explain how this would work?

Comment: Please, post anycode for a better help.

Comment: @SiloéBezerraBispo I don't really see a need to post code for this scenario, but if you insist, what code exactly should I add on to my question?

Comment: I don't see a problem using TextViews (presumably inside a ScrollView) instead of a ListView if the navigation items are known in advance and not determined dynamically. Alternatively, you could add the image as a header view on the ListView.

Comment: @Karakuri How would I go about adding the image as a header view on the `ListView`?

Comment: ListView.addHeaderView

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get home...

Comment: @Karakuri This works, but how would I be able to use dividers as shown [here](http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content) if I use one `ListView` with a header view?

Comment: Also, in Google's I/O App, there seems to be a `LinearLayout` at the bottom of the [navigation drawer](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/navdrawer.xml) which I think is responsible for the list of items shown. Could someone explain how this works?

Comment: Check my code here you will got your all answer, but you have to spend sometime: https://github.com/dhaval0122/ActionBar-Navigation-Tabs

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I have had a look at your answer and was wondering what the `ScrimInsetsScrollView` is, as defined in [this layout file](https://github.com/dhaval0122/ActionBar-Navigation-Tabs/blob/master/MaterialDesign/app/src/main/res/layout/google_io_drawer.xml).

Comment: Its custom class used to draw components like overlay action bar, navigation bar for (>= API 21).

Comment: https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer/blob/master/README.md this library does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> only the ListView scrolls, and the ImageView stays as it is

It sounds like your drawer contains an `ImageView` at the top and then a `ListView` follows. With this configuration only the `ListView` will scroll (because it's the only view that's scrollable).

You need to add the `ImageView` as a header which is always at the beginning of the list. As one of the comments suggested, do `listView.addHeaderView`.

> there seems to be a LinearLayout at the bottom of the navigation
>   drawer layout which I think is responsible for the list of items
>   shown. Could someone explain how this would work?

They use the `LinearLayout` as a container to hold all the `TextView`s:

```
private void createNavDrawerItems() {
    mDrawerItemsListContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.navdrawer_items_list);
    ...
    int i = 0;
    for (int itemId : mNavDrawerItems) {
        mNavDrawerItemViews[i] = makeNavDrawerItem(itemId, mDrawerItemsListContainer);
        mDrawerItemsListContainer.addView(mNavDrawerItemViews[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

I believe the reason they use a `LinearLayout` and inflate all the items programmatically is to be able to use separator items easily:

```
private View makeNavDrawerItem(final int itemId, ViewGroup container) {
    ...
    if (itemId == NAVDRAWER_ITEM_SEPARATOR) {
        layoutToInflate = R.layout.navdrawer_separator;
    } else if (itemId == NAVDRAWER_ITEM_SEPARATOR_SPECIAL) {
        layoutToInflate = R.layout.navdrawer_separator;
    } else {
        layoutToInflate = R.layout.navdrawer_item;
    }
    ...
    return view;
}
```

In a `ListView` you'd have to create a separate item type and use the divider's layout there, which could possibly get more cumbersome.

**At first glance**, however, this code just seems to be re-inventing the wheel as all of this is possible with a `ListView`.

Comment: I like the idea of having `TextView`s shown in your answer mainly because I would be able to add separators and have more control over my layout.

Comment: You don't need to add individual separator views. LinearLayout can draw dividers between its children, just give it a drawable and call 'setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will see if I can implement the navigation drawer in this way into my app.

Comment: @Simas Where could I find the code you've posted (is it from Google's I/O app on GitHub)?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh yes it's from repository whose link you've provided. [BaseActivity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java) contains `createNavDrawerItems` method.

Answer (score 0):

As of 29th May 2015 (after *Google I/O 2015*), you can use the **Android Design Support Library** to add a [`NavigationView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) to your app(s). The [Android Developer Blogspot article](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) states the following:

> **Navigation View**
>
> The [navigation drawer](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) can be an important focal point for identity and navigation within your app and consistency in the design here can make a considerable difference in how easy your app is to navigate, particularly for first time users. [`NavigationView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) makes this easier by providing the framework you need for the navigation drawer as well as the ability to inflate your navigation items through a menu resource.
>
> ...
>
> You can then start using the Design library with a single new dependency:
> `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`
>
> ...
>
> The Design library, AppCompat, and all of the Android Support Library are important tools in providing the building blocks needed to build a modern, great looking Android app without building everything from scratch.

Comment: But is the NavigationView scrollable as asked in the question?

Comment: I suppose it could be placed inside a `ScrollView` if necessary.

Comment: Placing it inside a scrollview causes problem when I call `DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);` in the onClick of the menu items. The error was no Drawer  found.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing scrollable Navigation Drawer using android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout and NavigationView could be even simpler than it is described at: http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

That article suggests adding each element of your application's Navigation Drawer as a Menu Item. This is cool and definitely a way to go for most of developers.
But what if you already has a Navigation Drawer implemented inside e.g. Linear Layout?

It appears that you can easily make your old good layout scrollable: just set it as a "app:headerLayout" of the NavigationView. No more changes are needed!
So, in a final solution you will have:

A layout of your Activity, similar to the above blog post, but without an "app:menu="@menu/drawer" attribute e.g. this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- your content layout -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And a layout for all your old Drawer content in the "drawer_header.xml" file, migrated without any changes to this scrollable Drawer, E.g. this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myFirstButton"
        android:onClick="onMyFirstButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/my_first_button_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goToTheTopButton"
        android:onClick="onGoToTheTopButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/go_to_the_top_title"/>

    <View style="@style/Divider"/>

    <!-- Some other "menu items" -->
</LinearLayout>
```

For full working example see this activity layout: https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/timeline.xml and this commit, where I migrated to a scrollable Navigation Drawer: https://github.com/andstatus/andstatus/commit/a80b299de714bdd65cacb138ffb31adc3ea23a98