# Using a ViewGroup as a list?

Tags: android, list, android-listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewgroup

**In some situations, it is better to use a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) to create lists, acting as something similar to a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), or [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).**

For example, I have a situation where I need to display a list of items in a `ViewGroup` which is a child of the root layout. **The root layout is scrollable (e.g. a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) or [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)) so it would be inappropriate to use another scrolling `View` to display list items.**

An example of this could be displaying list items in a [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) (of course in this case, you would not want too many list items as Cards are not meant for this). It would clearly not be right to use a scrolling layout inside your Cards, especially if the Cards are part of a scrolling root layout.

Another example could be creating a Navigation Drawer (of course after Google I/O 2015, there is the *Design Support Library*, so using a [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) would be far simpler and easier). But before the Design Support Library, you had to populate a `ViewGroup` (likely a [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) with items to display in the Navigation drawer, as the root layout of the drawer had to be scrollable. For more information about this scenario, I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084530/best-way-of-implementing-a-scrolling-navigation-drawer).

The point of the question is that there is no simple way to use a `ViewGroup` as a list layout, so many of us tend to use complicated solutions to disable scrolling on a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. Yes, the scrolling on the `ListView` can be disabled, but there is usually still a Lint warning. Therefore, **using `ViewGroup` lists can be also thought of as an alternate solution to disabling scrolling on scroll `View`s**.

**So is there a simple way to use `ViewGroup`s as lists?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by how Google populated list items in a `LinearLayout` in a Navigation Drawer, in their 2014 Google I/O app, I created a Gist that can populate list items in a `ViewGroup`.

The Gist, titled [`ViewGroupAdapter`, can be found here](https://gist.github.com/FarbodSalamat-Zadeh/6f56a412a15cac9a8c01).

I will continue to update and improve the Gist, if this solution becomes popular.

Comment: The problem with this adapter though is that it doesn't recycle views. So if you have more than 10 or so views you will start to notice a performance hit. This is not a workable solution for dynamic content.

Comment: @DavidArgyleThacker Fair point, however I intended it to be used for a small number of items. If the number of items becomes more than a page long, it would probably be more appropriate to use a scrolling view (i.e. `ListView` or `RecyclerView`). I may decide later on to add improvements however.